# Optimize file system for Linux web server with SSD and HDD

Tags: linux, filesystems, centos7, ssd

I have just taken delivery of a new Centos 7 web server which comes with a 4Tb HDD and 240Gb SSD. Both are hardware RAID.

As it stands everything is installed on the SSD. I will need more than 240Gb space and would like some ideas on how to set the file system up to best take advantage of the SSD.

For example, is it a good idea to put the mySQL files on the SSD? And will it make any difference where the website scripts are?

Comment: This can't really be answered by anyone except yourself. You need to know how the different components of your setup are used and what would profit most from fast disk access.

Comment: @Sven I'm really looking for a basic set up that can be further optimised. As the title says it is a web server so this will involve the usual components - php, mySQL, Apache/nginx plus a various caching - some file-based and some memory based...

Surely there's a rough guideline based on this. Even if it is tweaked afterwards.

Comment: `Even if it is tweaked afterwards. ` That's the point. Set your system up, set up monitoring and observe. Then optimize.

Comment: i'd use zfs. make a small / partition on the ssd. then set up a zfs pool using the hdd and set up additional partitions on the SSD for cache and ZIL. this way the SSD can cache reads and writes to the HDD...